# How can I be certain that a .vhd file contains an Azure VM snapshot?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cli, azure-vm

How can I be certain that a .vhd file contains an Azure VM snapshot? And how can I recover said snapshot. I have read MS Learn documentation and it appears that there are multiple ways to do this.

I uploaded an OS and DATA disk into Azure Storage Explorer, mind you that these files were very plainly named "abcd" and at first did NOT have any file extensions (.dmg, .exe, .vhd, etc.) with trial, error and some research I found out that I had to manually rename the files with the .vhd extensions then uploaded them into an Azure storage account. And here is where I am stuck:

Do I need to create a managed disk from these .vhd files and then create the VM? Or do I first need to make a snapshot and restore said VM from the OS .vhd file? What is the best way to go about and recover this VM or the proper steps?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions on creating an Azure VM from a VHD file can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized-portal?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404). You will need to make sure that the VHD meets the pre-requisites for use in Azure, you can't just use any old VHD. You can see these requirements [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image?source=recommendations?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404).